# Flutter Firestore left join?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, left-join

i have a problem with code below and some one told me to search about "Left Join" in firebase and i can't direct example , my code :

```
  List<dynamic> contactTraces = [];
  List<dynamic> contactTimes = [];
  List<dynamic> contactLocations = [];
  List<dynamic> status = [];

  void addContactsToList() async {
    await getCurrentUser();

    _firestore
        .collection('users')
        .document(loggedInUser.email)
        .collection('met_with')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) {
      for (var doc in snapshot.documents) {
        String email = doc.documentID;
        // print(email);
        String currUsername = doc.data['username'];
        DateTime currTime = doc.data.containsKey('contact time')
            ? (doc.data['contact time'] as Timestamp).toDate()
            : null;
        String currLocation = doc.data.containsKey('contact location')
            ? doc.data['contact location']
            : null;

        if (!contactTraces.contains(currUsername)) {
          _firestore.collection('users').document(email).get().then((value) {
            status.add(value.data["status"]);
          });

          contactTraces.add(currUsername);
          contactTimes.add(currTime);
          contactLocations.add(currLocation);
        }
      }
      setState(() {});
      print(loggedInUser.email);
    });
  }
```

my problem with with this line above :

```
  _firestore.collection('users').document(email).get().then((value) {
    status.add(value.data["status"]);
```

it takes time more than Others List like contactTimes , contactLocations to fetch "Status" , because it given null in Build .

here is the problem : listview can't await till this list [status] filled becouse it take time for fetch data:

```
infection: status.length == 0 ? 'checking' : status[index],
```

in here

```
  Expanded(
    flex: 2,
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ContactCard(
            imagePath: 'images/profile1.jpg',
            email: contactTraces[index],
            infection: status.length == 0 ? 'checking' : status[index],
            contactUsername: contactTraces[index],
            contactTime: contactTimes[index],
            contactLocation: contactLocations[index],
          );
        },
        itemCount: contactTraces.length,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, but I can tell you there are no join queries in Firestore.

Comment: i update my question so you can look for the last section .